# Does to good to do string concatination at SSRS report or its good to use SQL query for that?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am working on SSRS report and I have some column values to be concat while displaying in the report. So does to advisable to do that at report end or I have to do it at SQL query and bind that value directly to the report.

I am having 4 columns that I have to concat to single column while binding it to report.

there are three different ways to do that,

1. Can do at SQL query to get combined column.
2. Can create expression while binding dataset to tablix.
3. Create a calculated field in dataset and bind that to my tablix.

from above three which one is advisable to get better performance.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad but let me put it this way.

If you put business rules in the database then they can be consistently reused by many things beyond SSRS, for example, Excel, Power BI, data extracts

The downside is that it is often more technically difficult to consistently apply rules at a lower level like this. In other words you need a SQL Developer to do this properly rather than if you did the calc in SSRS, in which case you just need a SSRS developer.

So if you have a team full of SSRS developers, then it's going to be easier to create and maintain rules in SSRS, but the downside is these rules can't be reused by anything else.

Short answer: do it in a view in the database unless this is going to be difficult to maintain because your team doesn't have any SQL skills.

Comment: Yeah that's true as SSRS rules are used per report we can't reuse it. And for view yes I can reuse or create multiple views.

Comment: but sometime view is also hard to maintain as if multiple persons are working then its hard to check dependency of the view with SSRS report. We need to be specific in terms of giving name of the report. So it also been an overhead

Comment: Correct. Sounds like you’ve already thought about it. Consistency and naming standards help.